# For Oracle Reports, How to retrieve a report from the Forms Menu

Tags: migration, weblogic, weblogic12c, oracleforms, oraclereports

We are migrating Oracle Forms and Reports from 6i to 12c.

1. Migrated all .fmb, .rdf, .mmd, .pll from 6i to 12c.
2. Compiled them to .fmx, .rep, .mmx
3. Forms are working and being displayed when run via URL (http://localhost:8001/forms/frmservlet?config=form.fmx&userid=userid/pwd@dbname)
4. I can even view the standalone Reports using the URL in IE (http://hostname:port/reports/rwservlet?userid=userid=userid/pwd@dbname+destype=cache+desformat=html+report=reportname.rdf), but when a report is called in Forms Menu Item (i.e. from the Point 3 URL) won't work.

The error I get for all the reports is - FRM - 41219 - Cannot find report : invalid ID

When migrated the code the reports is changed  from   RUN_PRODUCT(REPORTS,'reportname',synchronous,runtime,filesystem,'',null); to rp2rro.rp2rro_run_product(REPORTS,'reportname',synchronous,runtime,filesystem,'',null);

Still no luck in displaying the Report in Forms Menu.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try to see if you can a report running with RUN_REPORT_OBJECT first.  The RP2RRO is an artefact of the migration utility - perhaps something is wrong in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you used to get the jobID in version 6 is slightly different in modern versions.  You may need to change your code a bit.  Check out the latest version of the Forms and Reports Integration Guide  https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/documentation/formsreportsintegration-12c-3014203.pdf